# String initialization problem explanation

Tags: c++, string, initialization, declaration

I am just curious about this:

```
std::string s(10);
```

It doesn't work. I would like to know the reason why it doesn't make a string with 10 elements. This is probably an easy question but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize an std::string with a length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27370480/how-to-initialize-an-stdstring-with-a-length)

Comment: There's no version of class `std::string` constructor that takes an int. If you want for some reason to create one: `std::string s(10, '');` This will create a string object of size 10 empty characters.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` has many [constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).

If You want a string with an explicit length, then a character has to be specified which will be used to fill this string:

```
std::string s(10, ' ');
```