# Rcpp string initialization constructor not found

Tags: c++, clang, rcpp

EDIT: the source of the error was a typo. Apologies for the confusion, but thanks to the many people who contributed valuable peripheral advise in comments.

The below code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
#include <cfloat>
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <cassert>
using namespace Rcpp;

int test(){
  std::string s(2,"");
  return 1;
}
```

induces the following IDE error:

```
no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::string'
```

Running the code in R generates an inexpressive seg fault, but I hope the above is sufficient. I see that in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30461583/no-matching-constructor-for-initialization-of-string-aka-basic-stringchar) the consensus is that this may happen when the used clang version is outmoded (clang++3.7 being the passing build). Having referred to this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33603027/get-apple-clang-version-and-corresponding-upstream-llvm-version) and seeing that my machine (macos) is running the following clang:

```
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.59)
```

I'm not sure that the issue I'm running into is a duplicate of the one featured in the above discussion.

If I had to guess, the source of the issue is likely the compiler version, something about rcpp, or a library conflict.

EDIT: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27370480/how-to-initialize-an-stdstring-with-a-length) and [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) are the sources which led me to believe that std ships with a default string constructor (see fill (6) for latter)

Comment: What are you trying to do with your string constructor? And which of the many overloads do you think should match the (`int`, `const char*`) argument list?

Comment: As an aside, you don't need all the extra include statements as including `Rcpp.h` will pull these in---it certainly does so for `string`.

Comment: Vote to lose as non-reproducable / typo, as OP got confused about `""` and `''` (see answer below).

Answer (score 1):

Well?

```
  std::string s(2,"");
```

> no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::string'

Exactly what it says in the error message, `std::string` does not have a [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) that matches your `int, char const *` arguments.

> If I had to guess, the source of the issue is likely the compiler version, something about rcpp, or a library conflict.

No, the issue is that there is no constructor matching your initialization attempt of `std::string`. If you had attempted to reduce the example even further -- i.e., removing all `include`s other than the one you are actually using (`<string>`), that might have become apparent.

Comment: Hi DevSolar, thanks for the quick answer. I edited the answer with sources to which I had referred when surmising that there exists such a constructor

Comment: @JoshPurtell: That constructor variant ou pointed out takes a *character* as second argument, not a string literal. That would then have to be `s(2, '\0')` (which is a questionable choice for an initialization; why would you want that?). -- Sidenote: cppreference.com is generally considered to be a higher quality resource than cplusplus.com, which has somewhat of a history of being just slightly wrong here and there...

Comment: Ok, perfect. It's been a while since I've used c++ and the difference between ' and '' slipped my mind. I assume (?) that it would be best for me to delete the answer, but if you prefer I heavily edit it to reflect the basic nature of the error so that your answer is not lost, let me know.

Comment: @JoshPurtell: Nah, it's good. I'll vote for close as "typo", and that will probably be it. You shouldn't delete questions that are already answered. The SO engine frowns on that.

Comment: Ok, makes sense, thanks

Comment: The reason I wanted to initialize with a certain char is that initializing just using char s[2] generated undefined behavior in my code, and I wanted to see if there was some subtle memory issue at play. It turns out I was correct(?) and the undefined behavior ceased once I used the above initialization. FWIW

Comment: @JoshPurtell: Uh... uh... C++ is very much **not** a "trial & error" language... just because it stopped blowing up in your face doesn't mean that UB went away, and / or won't blow up in your face at some later point. I seriously doubt that something that got "fixed" by an initialization like that is correct code. Perhaps post another question on that...